# Analytic function - Comparing values using LAG()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

Assume following data:

```
| Col1  |   Col2      |
| 3     |  20-dec-15  |
| 4     |  20-dec-15  |
| 8     |  25-dec-15  |
|10     |  25-dec-15  |
```

I have to compare the values of column `Col1` for a particular date.

For Example: For 20-dec-15 changes occured as 3 changed to 4.

I have to solve this using an analytical function.

Following is the query which I am using

```
decode(LAG(Col1,1,Col1) OVER (partition by Col2 order by Col2),Col1,0,1) Changes
```

As `Col2` is date column, Partition by date is not working for me. Can we apply date column as Partition?

Expected Result should be:

```
| Changes  | 
| 0        |
| 1        |
| 0        |
| 1        |
```

Here 1 means Change occured while comparing for same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `trunc()` in order to reset the time part to `00:00:00` but you should still keep `order by col2` so that all rows on the same day are ordered by the time part:

I also prefer an explicit `case` for this kind of comparison, personally I find the decode() really hard to read:

```
select case 
         when col1 = lag(col1,1,col1) over (partition by trunc(col2) order by col2) then 0 
         else 1
       end as changes
from the_table;
```

Comment: I tried with to_date(col2) , that seems to be working.

Comment: @subi_speedrunner: `to_date()` converts a **`varchar`** value into a `date` value. Do ***not*** use it on columns defined as `date`. It will first implicitly convert the `date` to a `varchar` just to convert it back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I will make sure not to use `to_date()` with a `Date` field.